# Installing NodeJS on AWS Lambda Python Container Image

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a custom docker image starting from

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
```

This docker image only has Python installed but I also want to install NodeJS and use NPM to install aws-cdk on it and deploy  a stack to CloudFormation via the python lambda. I've tried a bunch of different ways to install NodeJS but I haven't been able to get it working. This is what I have so far with some of the statements commented out (which I tested but didn't work).

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
# FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-instructions

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install packages
# RUN yum -y update && \
#    yum -y install wget && \
#    yum install -y tar.x86_64 && \
#    yum clean all

# RUN yum install nodejs npm
# RUN touch ~/.bashrc && chmod +x ~/.bashrc
# RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
# RUN . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install node
RUN yum update
RUN yum install https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_20.x/nodistro/repo/nodesource-release-nodistro-1.noarch.rpm -y
RUN yum install nsolid -y
# RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash -
RUN yum install nodejs

RUN yum install -y python3
RUN yum install -y python3-pip
# RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt



# Update NPM
RUN npm update -g
# Install AWSCLI
RUN pip3 install --upgrade awscli
# Install cdk
RUN npm install -g aws-cdk
RUN cdk --version

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "cdk_handler.handler" ]
```

The error when I try to build this specific image is:

```
1.950 Error: Package: nodesource-release-nodistro-1.noarch (/nodesource-release-nodistro-1.noarch)
1.950            Requires: glibc >= 2.28
1.950            Installed: glibc-2.26-63.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
1.950                glibc = 2.26-63.amzn2
1.950            Available: glibc-2.25-10.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
1.950                glibc = 2.25-10.amzn2.0.1
1.950            Available: glibc-2.26-27.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
1.950                glibc = 2.26-27.amzn2.0.4
1.950            Available: glibc-2.26-27.amzn2.0.5.i686 (amzn2-core)
1.950                glibc = 2.26-27.amzn2.0.5
...
```

Simply trying the

```
RUN yum install nodejs
```

results in the following error:

```
 > [ 4/11] RUN yum install nodejs:
0.401 Loaded plugins: ovl
0.620 No package nodejs available.
0.633 Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Hello, please share more information about the errors you are seeing. You can add snippets

Comment: Updated to include the errors

Answer (score 2):

This image is running Amazon Linux 2, which does not support Node 18 and above. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

```
#5 [2/12] RUN cat /etc/os-release
#5 0.194 NAME="Amazon Linux"
#5 0.194 VERSION="2"
#5 0.194 ID="amzn"
#5 0.194 ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
#5 0.194 VERSION_ID="2"
#5 0.194 PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
#5 0.194 ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
#5 0.194 CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
#5 0.194 HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
#5 0.194 VARIANT_ID="202308151228-2.0.1114.0"
#5 DONE 0.2s
```

You should use Node 16 instead, which works

```
RUN yum install https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_16.x/nodistro/repo/nodesource-release-nodistro-1.noarch.rpm -y
```

Also FYI that the nsolid install doesn't work. You can remove it if not important to you. Otherwise, follow the instructions here to resolve that  https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/4.10/docs#installation

Comment: Nvm, I tried this but when I run `RUN node -v` in the docker container after running the above it says `0.426 /bin/sh: node: command not found`